# javascript event listener for syntax and internal errors

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am working on a function to track anytime there is a js error on a page.  I have 4/6 error types working but can't seem to figure out a function for syntax errors, or do they just stop script execution to the point it doesn't function?  <s>Also, I am not sure how to test for internal errors?</s>  Edit: InternalError is only in firefox, <s>but need a test for EvalError, which I will post separately</s>. Another Edit: it appears EvalError is legacy and not fully supported by modern browsers.

No libraries such as jQuery can be used, only native js.

**Here is the code with the answer added:**

```
   errorTracking = function errorCaught( ev ) {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '';
    var errFile = '';
    var errLine = '';
    if(ev.filename) { errFile = ev.filename; }
    if(ev.lineno) { errLine = ev.lineno; }
    var errStr = 'ERROR: ' + ev.error + ', LOCATION: ' + errFile + ', LINE NUMBER:' + errLine;
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '<strong>Message:</strong> ' + ev.error + '<br /><strong>Location:</strong> ' + errFile + '<br /><strong>Line Number:</strong> ' + errLine;
    // Omniture Error Tracking.
    //_satellite.setVar('jsError', errStr);
  ev.preventDefault();
};

if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener( "error", errorTracking, false );
    document.getElementById('errRef').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var refErr = asdf.asdf.length;
    });
    document.getElementById('errTyp').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var typeErrVar = null;
        var typeErr = typeErrVar();
    });
    document.getElementById('errRan').addEventListener('click', function() {
        Array.apply(null, new Array(1000000)).map(Math.random);
    });
    document.getElementById('errURI').addEventListener('click', function() {
        decodeURIComponent("%");
    });
    document.getElementById('errSyn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.text = document.getElementById('error');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    });
    document.getElementById('errEva').addEventListener('click', function() {
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swv55c35/17/

Comment: It would be interesting to see if you could test for syntax errors. Considering they simply stop execution, I don't know how you'd tell if one has happened. But I simply don't have the knowledge to answer that for sure.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd need to use a `try` with an `eval()` call and  then `catch` the error from there, but thats really less than ideal.

Comment: yeah if it was a specific function but this is just sort of a global listener because there are a lot of 3rd party scripts causing a variety of errors we are trying to debug and track.

Comment: I guess I'm mostly looking for real world examples to cause these issues instead of just throw new err, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script/>`'s will be parsed completely, when a script contains a syntax-error, the entire script will be discarded. Create the syntax-error outside of the script that handles the errors, and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/swv55c35/3/

Comment: I see, this is more just a global listener for syntax errors because there are a lot of 3rd party scripts loaded to the site ,but it doesn't really look like there is a way to listen for these.  Thanks though

Comment: It's a matter of time. When you load a  script before you've added the error-listener(in the fiddle the error-handling will be initialized onload), an syntax-error in the external script can't be handled. For me it works with a 3rd-party script too, but I always get only the message "Script error" and line:0 (in Firefox and IE I get at least the location, in chrome not ): http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/hkvd1xnj/

Comment: I see what you're saying, as long as errorTracking() is loaded and the syntax error is in an external file or in a separate <script> block inline on the page it will catch the error.  Thanks!